# Suspended accounts

Tags: discussion, policy

We've been discussing on chat that recently two accounts were suspended. Honestly, I don't remember anything such on this site. The [general policy](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/04/06/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/) of this measure known, but what warrants such a punishment on MY? What is public about the background of these two particular cases?

Comment: Is there a synopsis of the protocol?

Comment: @Al I've only seen this linked blog post

Comment: One of these accounts at least was suspended before. Others were as well. They way you notice it is their score goes to 1, if you click on the user name it tells you the public reason and timeline for suspension.

Comment: It's sad. I would prefer suppression of posts instead of suspension of users

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally speaking (and I can't think of any exceptions of the top of my head, though they may well exist), Mi Yodeya's moderators use suspensions for the standard reasons used network-wide, or close variations thereof. Again generally speaking, we use suspensions to interrupt a pattern of behavior that we consider to be harmful to the community or our collection of content, to reinforce requests for changes in behavior that we have already made, either in public or in private.

As a matter of policy, we don't discuss individual cases of private communications, including suspension, in public.

Comment: I mean, do you send an e-mail to the user in advance that her/his behaviour raises concerns? Or how does it work?

Comment: @Kazibácsi The Stack Exchange tool provides us a means to send ["moderator messages"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94779/how-do-we-see-the-private-messages-that-moderators-sent-us) that can be viewed only by the user addressed, this community's moderators, and SE staff.